# Free dynamically allocated memory in C

Tags: c

because I am new in C, I am not sure how to ask it, but here is my Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE 500

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    for (int j=0; j<ARRAY_SIZE; ++j) {
        printf("Memory Size: %d\n", j);
        int bytes = (1024*1024);
        char *data;
        data = (char *) malloc(bytes);
        for(int i=0;i<bytes;i++){
            data[i] = (char) rand();
        }
    }
    //Free all Char*data that I have declared inside the for loop here
    return 0;

}
```

So I need to free my data variables that I have allocated inside the for loop. How is it possible? I am testing some portion of my memory blocks. So I am running it because I wanna see how far it goes. So the above code gets me to that point. Now I am trying to run a loop below threshold point so that I can assure, the memory that I am working with is good and can sustain. To do so, I need to clear the memory that I have created inside the loop.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You might like to review [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2410359)

Comment: What OS are you targeting? If it's a *nix or Windows OS, then your code may not ever detect bad RAM, unless you get lucky. To test RAM, you'll need access to the physical memory of the device, and that requires the use of non-portable OS API's.

Comment: I am working on Linux... SO the issue is, it can not un-tar a file above 40MB. I am pretty sure its a memory issue. But to be sure, I am running this test. And my partition is mapped to RAM

Comment: Compile your code with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`, fix all the warnings, then use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll want an array of pointers and then free those pointers after the loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
    
#define ARRAY_SIZE 500
    
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char * data[ARRAY_SIZE] = {0};
    for (int j=0; j<ARRAY_SIZE; ++j) {
        printf("Memory Size: %d\n", j);
        int bytes = (1024*1024);
        data[j] = (char *) malloc(bytes);
        for(int i=0;i<bytes;i++){
            data[j][i] = (char) rand();
        }
    }
    for (int j=0; j<ARRAY_SIZE; ++j) {
        free(data[j]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually it didn't worked. because data is representing bytes. Hence I got these errors.memtest_dynamic.c: In function 'main':
memtest_dynamic.c:20:25: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
                 data[i] = (char) rand();
                         ^
memtest_dynamic.c:20:25: warning: iteration 420u invokes undefined behavior [-Waggressive-loop-optimizations]
                 data[i] = (char) rand();
                         ^
memtest_dynamic.c:19:13: note: containing loop
             for(int i=0;i<bytes;i++){
             ^

Comment: My bad, I've updated the example.  I incorrectly had `data[j] = (char) rand();`
when I should have had `data[j][i] = (char) rand();`
my incorrect code was blowing away the pointer :(

Answer (score 0):

Since you assigned the return value of `malloc` to `data` which is defined inside of the loop, that memory is lost at the end of each iteration of the loop.

You need to add a call to `free` at the bottom of the loop.

```
for (int j=0; j<ARRAY_SIZE; ++j) {
    printf("Memory Size: %d\n", j);
    int bytes = (1024*1024);
    char *data;
    data = (char *) malloc(bytes);
    for(int i=0;i<bytes;i++){
        data[i] = (char) rand();
    }
    free(data);
}
```

Comment: I need to clear the data variable outside of the first loop. Otherwise if I free it inside, then everytime the same memory block will be used. I need to to do it right before the reurn 0 line.

Comment: @SubbirRahman You can't because the variable no longer exists.

Comment: I know. Any suggestion how I can write this code? Basically I want to use up to 500MB ram to test if my RAM is ok or not

Comment: Do you perhaps want an array of pointers?  Then you can assign the allocated memory to a member of an array defined outside the loop, then later use another loop to free the array members.

Comment: Actually it did not solved my problem. How can I use the pointer to the allocated memory?